# Знак равно в параметре action

Tags: php, html

Наткнулся на такую строчку кода:

```
action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>"
```

знаки вопроса как я понимаю выделяют php код, вопрос в том зачем после первого знака вопроса ставится знак равно, если и без него работает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это сокращенная запись PHP аля-echo.

Запись

```
<?= $a ?>
```

эквивалентна

```
<?php echo $a ?>
```

.